# jest.mockClear is not cleaning up the data neither the mockImplementation in the 'it' block is updating the value

Tags: typescript, jestjs

```
let mockFn;
beforeEach(() => {
    mockFn = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
     [{},{}]   
    });
    jest.spyOn(global, 'utilis').mockImplementation(mockFn);
})

it('d', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(global, 'utilis').clearMocks();
    mockFn = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => []);
    jest.spyOn(global, 'utilis').mockImplementation(mockFn);
})
```

If I am passing the above mock value in the beforeEach block, mockClear is working and the new value is also being mocked from 'it' block.
But if I pass array of objects

```
mockFn = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => [{},{}]   
    );
```

neither mockClear() or the new value is being updated. Can please help me with this issue.
Thanks